# Best way to show map of tagged posts?

Tags: tags, geo-data, map

This seems so simple that I'm tearing my hair out.

I want to add a page with a map showing all the posts with a particular tag. I want each marker to pop up with the title and the preview, allowing the visitor to click through and read the full post.

Ideally I want to be able to use an OpenStreetMap map as the background instead of Google.

I've had a look at geopress, geomashup, wpgeo and osm. They are all either low quality or lacking a key feature.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rolling your own.

Create a metabox that allows posts to store lats and longs on posts.  Then create a page that finds all the posts with the tags that you want that can grab the lats and longs from each post meta data.  Using that post meta data create a json variable in the html that includes all the lat long info for all the posts that have been returned.  Whatever mapping library you use can access the outputted json variable as the data to use for plotting the locations.

Comment: [My answer to Q18644](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/is-there-a-way-to-display-all-my-posts-on-a-single-google-map/107716#107716) do something like @Paul Sheldrake suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the official plugin for Geo Tagging ([Geolocation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geolocation/)) will soon support the features you're after! I've started to update the plugin myself, I've opened up a support post over at the wordpress support forums which you can see here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/updates-to-geolocation

The code base is rather messy at the moment I will admit, but everything seems to work ok at the moment, so we will see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth you might want to have a look at one other plugin: [gPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gpress/)

I've had a great experience on their support forums as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely give the plugin [Geo Mashup](http://wordpress.org/plugins/geo-mashup/) a try - it does exactly what you say on my page - in a query you specify the posts to display on the map. 
Very easy - and it uses Openstreetmap as the background data ..

Answer (score 0):

The best plugin I've found so far for this is [Mappress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/)...there is a pro version, which you might need. Rolling your own will be very involved, but of course will get you everything you want....so if you can get [mapppress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/) to meet your needs you'll save a lot of time.