# Is there a way to display all my posts on a single Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, geo-data

I'd like to "geotag" all my posts and display them on a single Google map.

Comment: I think you can solve this question by reading the answers to "[Best way to show map of tagged posts?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11248/best-way-to-show-map-of-tagged-posts)". If you can't solve it after reading that question, please edit your question to clarify what you tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 11):

Can do this **without** any plugin, you need only the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/).

Please note that if you plan to have 20 markers or more on a single page, you have to geolocate posts using coordinates and not addresses.

To save coordinates from an address you can:

1. manually use a service (something like [this](http://www.mygeoposition.com/))
2. call Google maps geocoding from WP admin when you create or update the post

How to implement the second option is not strictly related to the question, and I will not take it into account for my answer, but see this [Maps API example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) to see how simple is retrieve coordinates from an address.

So I will assume in this answer that posts have a custom field 'coords' where coordinates are stored as a string of two comma separated values, someting like: `'38.897683,-77.03649'`.

I also assume that there is a page template saved in the file 'page-google-map.php'.

Put the following code in `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_gmap' );

function enqueue_gmap() {
    // script goes only in the map page template
    if ( ! is_page_template('page-google-map.php') ) return;

    wp_register_script( 'google-maps-api', '//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', false, false );
    wp_register_script( 'posts_map', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/mygmap.js', false, false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps-api' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'posts_map' );

    // use a custom field on the map page to setup the zoom
    global $post;
    $zoom = (int) get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'map_zoom', true );
    if ( ! $zoom ) $zoom = 6;

    $map_data = array( 
        'markers' => array(), 
        'center'  => array( 41.890262, 12.492310 ), 
        'zoom'    => $zoom,
    );
    $lats  = array();
    $longs = array();

    // put here your query args
    $map_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, ) );

    // Loop
    if ( $map_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while( $map_query->have_posts() ) : $map_query->the_post();
            $meta_coords = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'coords', true );
            if ( $meta_coords ) {
                $coords = array_map('floatval', array_map( 'trim', explode( ",", $meta_coords) ) );
                $title = get_the_title();
                $link  = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink(), $title);
                $map_data['markers'][] = array(
                    'latlang' => $coords,
                    'title'   => $title,
                    'desc'    => '<h3 class="marker-title">'.$link.'</h3><div class="marker-desc">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div>',
                );
                $lats[]  = $coords[0];
                $longs[] = $coords[1];
            }
        endwhile;
        // auto calc map center
        if ( ! empty( $lats ) )
            $map_data['center'] = array( 
                ( max( $lats ) + min( $lats ) ) /2,
                ( max( $longs ) + min( $longs ) ) /2 
            );
    endif; // End Loop

    wp_reset_postdata;
    wp_localize_script( 'posts_map', 'map_data', $map_data );
}
```

As you can see, in the map page template, I enqueue

- the google map api script
- a script called `mygmap.js` located in 'js' subfolder of the theme

also, looping the posts, I populate an array `$map_data` and using `wp_localize_script` I pass this array to the js in the page.

Now, `mygmap.js` will contain:

```
function map_initialize() {
    var map_div     = document.getElementById( 'map' );
        map_markers = map_data.markers,
        map_center  = new google.maps.LatLng( map_data.center[0], map_data.center[1] ),
        map_zoom    = Number( map_data.zoom ),
        map         = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), {
            zoom      : map_zoom,
            center    : map_center,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        } );

    if ( map_markers.length ) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
            marker, 
            i;
        for ( i = 0; i < map_markers.length; i++ ) {  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(
                    map_markers[i]['latlang'][0], 
                    map_markers[i]['latlang'][1]
                ),
                title    : map_markers[i]['title'],
                map      : map
            } );
            google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', ( function( marker, i ) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent( map_markers[i]['desc'] );
                    infowindow.open( map, marker );
                }
            } )( marker, i ) );
        }
    }
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', map_initialize );
```

The javascript is not WP related, and I put here only to show the use of `map_data` var. I'm not a js developer and the code is more or less entirely taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

That's all. Just create the page template and insert a div with the id 'map', something like:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Of course the div can be styled with css, and note that also the info windows of markers  can be styled, too: in the css use `h3.marker-title` to style the info window title and `div.marker-desc` to style the content.

Note that the map center is automatically calculated and if you want to change the default zoom you have to put a custom field 'map_zoom' in the page assigned to the map page template.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've got a geocoder plugin that adds the coords with brakets around them to a custom field. Eg. `(37.983917, 23.729359899999963)` where can I edit the code so it can use the coords with brakets around them. My attempt just failed. Thanks for this answer though its awesome!

Comment: @stemie you can change `$meta_coords = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'coords', true );` to `$meta_coords = trim(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'coords', true ), '()');` and of course, replace `coords` to the actual field the plugin uses to store coordinates.

Comment: Hi there. I know this is pretty old, but I have not been able to implement it with the new WordPress 4.2 and the new Google Maps api. Is there anyone who can review it again? Thanks.

Comment: I am able to display the map with the center position, but I am not able to pull it the locations of my posts and when I view the codeview I only see the center position in the javascript that has been produced. Will this work with the new WordPress 4.2?

Comment: @exedesign2 honestly, I have no idea. I don't touch this code an Google since a long time now..