# Show posts on a Google Map

Tags: custom-field, google-maps, geo-data

Through the custom fields, I assigned to each post its geographic coordinates (latitude/longitude).

Now, I'd like to show a Google Maps with a marker for each post.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this effectively?

**EDIT:** Solved following [this G.M.'s answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/is-there-a-way-to-display-all-my-posts-on-a-single-google-map/107716#107716).

Comment: Yesterday I answered a very similar question, see [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/is-there-a-way-to-display-all-my-posts-on-a-single-google-map/107716#107716)

Comment: Thanks! With your solution I succeeded. There was a couple of typos I've corrected in the Javascript code. Please consider answer my original question, so I can accept your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't mind about accept the answer, I don't think is good to duplicate an anwer, even if working. Edit the question, instead, and write that you find solution with my aswer and link it. You can consider to upvote my answer, too, if you want :)

Comment: @gmazzap would you share with me how you resolve this issue? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways to proceed here. Here's one way to do it:

1. Find a JavaScript/jQuery plugin that works with map markers. I used [Mosne Map](http://www.mosne.it/playground/mosne_map/), it's old but it works.
2. Generate the HTML markup that the above plugin will use. I needed a more user-friendly way to add markers, so I utilized ACF's [Repeater Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) type for this because I had one page with a map, so it was easiest way to attach lat-lang coordinates to that page. Your case would probably be getting those posts with `WP_Query` and extracting the coordinates from each.
3. Tie it all together with a shortcode, so that the map can be shown on any page. Again, you don't need this, you can just include all the necessary JS, execute your `WP_Query`, and generate the necessary HTML anywhere you want to show the map.

Answer (score 1):

The best plugin I've found so far for this is [Mappress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/)...there is a pro version, which you might need. I've got it implemented [here](http://travel.shequine.com/map/) in the way you describe.