# How to pinpoint posts location with Google map v3?

Tags: google-maps

This has been edited because I had the wrong tutorial all along. I would like to pinpoint my WordPress posts location in a single Google Map using the Javascript Option V3. I have look all over, but there is nothing that works with the recent version of WordPress 4.2.
I don't wanna use a plugin because I would like to have more flexibility later and be able to control all the aspect of the map through PHP.
Any help will be appreciated.

I tried the following tutorial [Is there a way to display all my posts on a single Google Map?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/is-there-a-way-to-display-all-my-posts-on-a-single-google-map/107716#107716) , but no success.

I do believe the above tutorial will be great start though, so if someone can debug it to work with current WordPress version 4.2. That will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to check this [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/geo-my-wp/). This is the WP plugin which satisfies your all constraint. This plugin would be able to work with current WordPress version 4.2.

OR

You can check tutorial for [google map with wordpress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-google-maps-in-wordpress/).

Let me know if you face any further query/concern.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer. Please see [answer], more the section about link only answers

Comment: I appreciate your help, but as I mentioned I don't wanna use a plugin. I want to figure this out with either the mentioned tutorial above or simply using using post query to populate the the variables of the google maps api.